# I want to add a JScrollPane

Tags: java

I want to add a scroll panel in a panel that is within a tab panel ( for example say 'A') and 'A' is also within an another tab Panel . I want to use java swing.

Comment: Try the [NetBeans IDE](http://www.netbeans.org/). It has a nice GUI editor and you can inspect the code how everything was done.

Comment: Start with [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to use tabbed panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) and [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: @AdilSoomro I want a Porsche!

Comment: @MadProgrammer you see it, you love it, and then you buy it, a decade has been past.

Answer (score 0):

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 10);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
add(scrollPane);
```

That's how you create a basic text area wrapped in a scroll pane. You should be able to work from that and achieve what you want to achieve.